# Conexión indicador de peso

Tags: c#

Tengo un indicador de peso que tiene un IP 172.50.0.18 un puerto 3000  necesito conectar este indicador en un formulario es decir que en un textbox me muestre el peso 
como podría mostrar este peso en un formulario sencillo

**Ejemplo** 
indicador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

texbox con peso de indicador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO**

```
 private void ServidorIP()
        {
            //Crea objeto diccionario con los clientes ip disponibles
            Dictionary<string, IDCommunications_Ver2.TCPClientParameters.TCPParameters> _ClienteTCPIP =
                    new Dictionary<string, IDCommunications_Ver2.TCPClientParameters.TCPParameters>();

            //Por cada elemento de la lista de los indicadores que esten activos y que sean de tipo IP
            foreach (AccesoDatosEntity.sp_Ordenes_Consultar_ListarIndicadoresDisponibles_Result _Indicador in _LstIndicadoresDisponibles.Where(x => x.IdTipoConexion == "IP").ToList())
            {
                //Agrega al diccionario los dos objetos de las clases para la parametrizacion de los clientes ip
                _ClienteTCPIP.Add(_Indicador.IP, new IDCommunications_Ver2.TCPClientParameters.TCPParameters()
                {
                    _ComandoPeticion = _LstComandosIndicador.First(x => x.idTipoIndicador == _Indicador.IdTipoBascula).comando,
                    _EnviarComando = true,
                    _MensajeAcumulados = _IntApilacionesIndicador,
                    _TamanoLecturas = _IntTamanoRespuesta,
                    _TiempoEspera = _IntTiempoRespuesta,
                    _InicioTrama = _LstTiposIndicador.First(x => x.IdTipoIndicador == _Indicador.IdTipoBascula).InicioTrama,
                    _FinTrama = _LstTiposIndicador.First(x => x.IdTipoIndicador == _Indicador.IdTipoBascula).FinTrama
                });
            }

            RegistroTraza("Crear servidor ip:" + _StrDireccionIP + "-" + _IntPuertoIP.ToString());

            //Asigna memoria al objeto servidor de conexiones ip
            _ClsServidorIP = new IDCommunications_Ver2.IDTCPListener(_StrDireccionIP, 3000, _IntTiempoEspera, _ClienteTCPIP);

            //Asigna los eventos delegados del servidor ip
            _ClsServidorIP.CreationTCPClient += ServidorIP_CreationTCPClient;
            _ClsServidorIP.DisconnectTCPClient += ServidorIP_DisconnectTCPClient;
            _ClsServidorIP.ExceptionListener += ServidorIP_ExceptionListener;
            _ClsServidorIP.ExceptionListenerInt += ServidorIP_ExceptionListenerInt;
            _ClsServidorIP.ExceptionNewTCPClient += ServidorIP_ExceptionNewTCPClient;
            _ClsServidorIP.ExceptionRemove += ServidorIP_ExceptionRemove;
            _ClsServidorIP.ExceptionRemoveInt += ServidorIP_ExceptionRemoveInt;
            _ClsServidorIP.ExceptionStopServer += ServidorIP_ExceptionStopServer;
            _ClsServidorIP.ExceptionTCPClient += ServidorIP_ExceptionTCPClient;
            _ClsServidorIP.MessageSendTCPClient += ServidorIP_MessageSendTCPClient;
            _ClsServidorIP.ReceivedSendTCPClient += ServidorIP_ReceivedSendTCPClient;
            _ClsServidorIP.TCPClientClose += ServidorIP_TCPClientClose;

            RegistroTraza("Finalizar servidor ip");
        }
```

Comment: Generalmente este tipo de dispositivos tienen un protocolo para enviar peticiones de peso (o bien envían peso continuamente, pero esa alternativa no es necesariamente la mejor). Para tomar el peso debes abrir conexión a la IP/puerto que te indica, enviar un comando para solicitar peso (varía, pero a veces puede ser un W), y esperas la respuesta. Si colocas algo de código, de lo que llevas, te podemos apoyar mejor.

Comment: Puse una parte del código pero este código que me funciona pero es muy complejo ya que se guarda la ip en una base de datos  y mira que indicadores están disponibles pero lo que yo necesito es algo sencillo solo que me muestre el peso hacer la conexión

Comment: Ya probaste utilizando el SDK?

https://www.averyweigh-tronix.com/globalassets/products/software/mi-connect/mi-connect_spec_500865.pdf

Comment: No es primer vez que trabajo con esto

Comment: Me puedes ayudar con algo de documentación